# Have a unique Kafka ksqlDB event when a new MAX value occurs in a materialized view

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, event-driven-design

Getting confused with ksqlDB events and materialized views. I want to be notified in a dedicated topic / stream when a new high stock price occurs as determined in a table aggregate / materialized view but I'm getting the high price reported for every event rather than only when there is a new high price event.

Here is my working example / setup.

Create underlying stream and topic for stocks.

```
ksql> create stream stocks (symbol VARCHAR KEY, company VARCHAR, price DECIMAL(9, 2))
>  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='stocks', PARTITIONS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='json');

Message
----------------
Stream created
----------------
```

add some initial data on stock prices for Acme Corp

```
ksql> insert into stocks (symbol, company, price) values ('ACME', 'Acme Corp', 111.11);
ksql> insert into stocks (symbol, company, price) values ('ACME', 'Acme Corp', 111.12);
ksql> insert into stocks (symbol, company, price) values ('ACME', 'Acme Corp', 111.13);
```

Print underlying topic to prove data is there.

```
ksql> print 'stocks' from beginning limit 3;
Key format: KAFKA_INT or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2021/03/21 14:26:57.169 Z, key: 1094929733, value: {"COMPANY":"Acme Corp","PRICE":111.11}
rowtime: 2021/03/21 14:27:01.717 Z, key: 1094929733, value: {"COMPANY":"Acme Corp","PRICE":111.12}
rowtime: 2021/03/21 14:27:04.546 Z, key: 1094929733, value: {"COMPANY":"Acme Corp","PRICE":111.13}
Topic printing ceased
```

Create aggregate / materialized view to show highest stock prices.

```
ksql> create table stock_highs as
>  select symbol, max(price) as high
>  from stocks
>  group by symbol
>  emit changes;

 Message
--------------------------------------------
 Created query with ID CTAS_STOCK_HIGHS_115
--------------------------------------------
```

Query it for visual inspection.

```
ksql> select * from stock_highs where symbol = 'ACME';
+--------------+------------------------+
|SYMBOL        |HIGH                    |
+--------------+------------------------+
|ACME          |111.13                  |
Query terminated
```

Use consumer (aka print STOCK_HIGHS) in a separate terminal (terminal 2) of to watch for changes to the stock high price.

```
ksql> print STOCK_HIGHS from beginning;
Key format: KAFKA_INT or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2021/03/21 14:27:04.546 Z, key: 1094929733, value: {"HIGH":111.13}
```

Back in original terminal (terminal 1) with ksql client insert more data to force the stock high to be updated.

```
ksql> insert into stocks (symbol, company, price) values ('ACME', 'Acme Corp', 111.20);
ksql> insert into stocks (symbol, company, price) values ('ACME', 'Acme Corp', 111.15);
```

The above inserts should give a new high price of 111.20 and ignore the 111.15 price so, in my thinking and use case I'd want to get an event / message from the STOCK_HIGHS topic showing a new high stock price of 111.20 but not the 111.15 price.  However, I get two new events in the consumer (terminal 2).

```
ksql> print STOCK_HIGHS from beginning;
Key format: KAFKA_INT or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2021/03/21 14:27:04.546 Z, key: 1094929733, value: {"HIGH":111.13}
rowtime: 2021/03/21 14:37:51.234 Z, key: 1094929733, value: {"HIGH":111.20}
rowtime: 2021/03/21 14:39:03.301 Z, key: 1094929733, value: {"HIGH":111.20}
```

The problem is I really only want to be notified or "evented" when only new high prices are occuring that way I can have a consumer going off and doing something meaningful when there is a new high price established.